# Запуск скрипта JS в WebView

Tags: java, android-studio

В моем приложении реализовано WebView с динамической сменой ссылок. Я хотел бы привязать скрип js вебвизора для простмотра действий пользователей.

На данный момент я пытаюсь загрузить скрипт в

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
wv.loadUrl("javascript:" + getString(R.string.jsbody));
```

сам js выглядит так:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
   (function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a){m[i]=m[i]||function(){(m[i].a=m[i].a||[]).push(arguments)};
   m[i].l=1*new Date();k=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t) 
   [0],k.async=1,k.src=r,a.parentNode.insertBefore(k,a)})
   (window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");

   ym(********, "init", {
        clickmap:true,
        trackLinks:true,
        accurateTrackBounce:true,
        webvisor:true
   });
```

Вся эта сборка сработала ровно 2 раза. Сам визор не запустился, но в аналитике были зарегистрированы 2 посетителя. Возможно, я что-то делаю неправильно. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: я может ошибаюсь, но wv.loadUrl("javascript:"...) вроде должен вызывать УЖЕ СУЩЕСТВУЮЩИЕ методы в WebView. а вы пытаетесь ему впихнуть новый код.

Comment: Да, я знаю, но такой подход бы описан в английском стаке. Надежд я на него не возлагал.